# create continuous scale in increments of 2 or "n" numbers R

Tags: r, scale

Let's imagine I want to create a continuous scale of numbers and assign it to an object. I'd to the following:

```
a <- 1:100
```

This will give me an array that increments every 1 number.

Now what if I wanted to create a similar array but instead have it increment every other two numbers  so that I'm basically left with 50 values in that way:

```
a=    
 1 3 5 7 etc.
```

I have a feeling that that is not just an R thing of course because I have a feeling that it is basic programming stuff that I don't know... But couldn't find anything through my searches (which I think is probably due to bad keyword choice on my part).

Comment: Have you looked at the `seq` function yet?

Comment: I have now :) Seems like thats what I needed! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't aware of the function `seq()` as pointed by @Ananda. Thanks for the tip.

The way I would do this (in case someone has a similar question) would be as follows:

```
seq(from=1, to=100, by=2)
```